# Empty FactTable when using Talend

Tags: talend, business-intelligence, data-integration, talend-mdm

I constructed my database in mysql. I constructed next of the dimensions except (time dim).

[image]

After filling the fact table, I realize that it is always empty. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: we can't see the joins in your tMap; there is probably an error on the joined columns. For debug purpose, you can put all joins as 'left outer join' to begin, it will help you see which columns are not correctly retrieved.

Comment: @Corentin thank you for you response . I tried before left join and i got 3000 lines (with redondencies) so the idea to do innerjoin with 0 rows. Hope that im clear now